# Vuetify Tree-view --- Get parent node along with the children node

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

when I am trying to select a node in the Vuetify tree-view in leaf mode, I am getting only the leaf nodes in the v-model. Is there a way that I could get all the children node along with the selected parent node.

Vuetify Version: 2.2.18

Link to the code: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101

Result After selection:

[image]

Actual Result:

```
Child #1
Child #2
Grandchild #1
Grandchild #2
```

Expected Result:

```
Root
Child #1
Child #2
Child #3
Grandchild #1
Grandchild #2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that vuetify removes the parent nodes, as these contain all the child nodes. One solution is to build a computed flattened copy of the `items` that contains references to the parent nodes.

This can then be recursively looped through via a second computed property (`_selection`) which adds the parents of the selected items.

working example: https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/MWwqYBB?editors=1010

```
  computed : {
    _items () {
       const replaceChildren = (obj,parent) => {
         const clone = Object.assign({},obj)
         delete clone.children
         if (parent) clone.parent = parent
         return clone
       }

       const addItems = (arr,parent) => {
         const items = arr.reduce((acc,x)=>{

           acc.push(replaceChildren(x,parent))

           if (x.children) {
             acc.push(addItems(x.children, x.id))
           }
           return acc
         },[])

         return items.flat()
       }

       return addItems(this.items).reduce((acc,x)=>{
         acc[x.id]=x
         return acc
       },{})
    },
    _selection () {
       const proxy = {}
       addParents = (x, all) => {
         const parentId = this._items[x.id].parent
         if (parentId) {
           if (all) addParents(this._items[parentId])
           proxy[parentId] = this._items[parentId]
         }
       }
       this.selection.forEach(x=>{
         addParents(x,this.allParentNodes)
         proxy[x.id] = x
       })
      return Object.values(proxy)
    }
  },
```

EDIT:

The recursion can be toggled with the allParentNodes property.

```
data : ()=> ({
  allParentNodes : true,
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the code and it works exactly fine when the tree has one level. If it has more levels I am not getting the expected result.                                  
Code Pen:https://codepen.io/eajithkumar128/pen/oNXPNOQ?editors=1010                                 On selecting Child3 in the above-given code I am not getting the expected result

Comment: You're right. The updated answer is a more robust approach.

Comment: I have tried the above solution but I am getting all the parents above it but I need only the selected parent. I changed the vuetify version to 2.2.17, in this version I am able to get what is expected from the v-model itself. v-model gives all the leaf nodes along with the parent node selected in this version.

Comment: Ok, I made it add all the parent nodes because 'Root' was included in your expected result list.

Comment: My expectation is I need only the selected parent. Anyway thanks for the response, this may help me in future

Comment: I've added a property to toggle between all parent nodes and just the selected parent

Comment: I checked this, it works perfectly for all test case but if a parent doesn't have direct leaf nodes, I am not getting the selected parent. consider in the above example take out the "child #1" from the object and try selecting the root element it won't give the selected parent "Root"

Comment: I thought of another approach for solving this, correct me if any flaws in that. instead of leaf mode , select the independent mode whenever the user selects a parent element I would check if it has any children recursively and select all the childrens under it and would do the same for deselection will it work

Answer (score 9):

TLDR: use `selection-type="fix your god damn documentation"`

I know that a moment has passed since this question was asked but I actually found out something interesting having the same problem

Turns out you can achieve desired result with a change in one line of code

You just have to specify `selection-type` as any string that isn't `leaf` or `independent`. Note that `selection-type` must not be omitted for desired result (it would otherwise default into `leaf`)

Personally I use `fix your god damn documentation` to relieve my frustration with said thing (info on described behaviouor is nowhere to be found in there)

Place that lead me to that solution: https://gitmemory.com/issue/vuetifyjs/vuetify/9088/543108633

Codepen: https://codepen.io/liath44/pen/RwoKxVB

Comment: works probably only in version 2.4+ but saved my ass... thank you, I used "fix your god damn documentation" in your honor

Comment: Even if it'ok on codepen I don't manage to make this work, I don't understand why also the console is full of warning even on codepen, someone have an alternative ?

Comment: Ok it's working ! Wrong cache buid.
I had to use https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/vuetifyjs/vuetify/9088/606826313 to avoid spam warning in the console. Maybe this will be fix in the future ?

Comment: In my opinion it's not working as I would like. If I only select "Grandchild #2" I would have "Root", "Child #3" and "Grandchild #2" on the selection nodes. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Wow, thank you for saving the day. +1 on using `selection-type="fix your god damn documentation"`

Comment: Now you can use :selection-type="null" to achieve the same ;)

Comment: Works with the latest Vuetify 2 version! Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much!!! vuetify 2.3 works  perfectly

Comment: Using `:selection-type="null"` also gets rid of the `custom prop` validation error :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by iterating over the internal nodes array of the treeview component, whenever the selection changes.

It seems the nodes array is a flattened version of the array containing an isSelected property along with the item.

In template:

```
<v-treeview
      ref="tree"
      v-model="selection"
      ...
></v-treeview>
```

In script:

```
data() {
    return {
        selection: [],
        selectionWithParents: []
    }
},
watch: {
    selection() {
      let _selectedNodes = []
      let _treenodes = this.$refs['tree'].nodes

      for (const key in _treenodes) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(_treenodes, key)) {
          const node = _treenodes[key];
          if (node.isSelected) _selectedNodes.push(node.item)
        }
      }
  
      this.selectionWithParents = _selectedNodes;
    }
}
```

Works fine in Vuetify v2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const indexParent = this.data.findIndex(parent => parent.id == itemClicked.id_of_parent)
const indexChildren = this.data[indexParent].children.indexOf(indexChildren)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).